# Visual Studio Plug-in (vsix) Menu Commands Localization

Tags: vsix, vsixmanifest

I encountered a problem. I created a plug-in project in VS2022 (17.6), and then tried to localize the menu of the plug-in. I modified it many times with reference to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/localizing-menu-commands?view=vs-2022), but it kept failing. I didn't find any problems.

The following is a screenshot of the test case:

(1) [Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsL97.png)

(2) [Project configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLwjF.png)

(3) [AssemblyInfo.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afIW0.png)

I read the documentation carefully and spent a long time without finding any problems. I hope everyone can help me.

This is the wrong demo path: [Vsix Demo](https://github.com/huangzhihao233/Vsix.git)

Comment: What was the failures?

Comment: After I localized according to the documentation, the plugin disappeared in VS, and no error was reported during startup.
Tips: After right clicking on the .cs file, the application should appear in the popup menu

Comment: I have it working, maybe some ideas /difference are visible here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/blob/master/src/GUI/EFCorePowerTools/EFCorePowerToolsPackage.zh-Hans.vsct

Comment: Unbelievable, why after I start VS2022 here, there is no display in the right-click menu.

Comment: I have referred to the efcorepowertools open source plug-in before, and it seems that no problem was found.

Comment: Actually someone contributed Spanish recently and had never got the menu localication to work

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I already solved this problem in September); after testing, I think this is a VS Studio problem, see the reply below for details.

Answer (score 0):

By re-creating a new plug-in project, I found that after VS compilation is completed, an empty resource file (EmptyResource.resx) will be generated by default in the "obj" directory, but the console prompts that the resource file does not exist (actually exists) and a warning message : "VSSDK1009: Could not find any matching cto files to merge for resource 'obj\Debug\EmptyResource.resources". I think this is the reason why the plug-in disappears in VS (that is, the menu resources cannot be merged into the .cto file), and I also found that the decompiled resource DLL file does not output menu resources.

So my solution: Create two resource files (zh-hans, en-US) without content and configure them as MergeWithCTO in the project file。
eg:

```
   <EmbeddedResource Include="VSpackage.zh-Hans.resx">
     ....
     <MergeWithCTO>true</MergeWithCTO>
   </EmbeddedResource>
```